# Bash script for azure cli query, output not quite what I want

Tags: bash, azure-cli, jmespath

I have a script that I want to use for Azure to return the resource group, storage account name, storage container name, name of the blob object, size of the blob object, and storage tier.

I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

resourceGroup=$1
storageAccount=$2

containers="$(az storage container list --account-name $2 --auth-mode login --query "[].[name]" -o tsv)"
        for c in $containers
                do
                        blob_info=$(az storage blob list --account-name $2 \
                        --auth-mode login --container-name ${c} \
                        --query "[].[container,name,properties.contentLength,properties.blobTier]" 
                        -o tsv)
                        echo "$resourceGroup,$storageAccount,$blob_info" | tr '\t' ','
                done
```

When there are multiple blob items in the JSON I expect the output to show the resource group and storage account along with the complete blob_info for every blob item like this:

```
$resourceGroup,$storageAccount,$blob_info
$resourceGroup,$storageAccount,$blob_info
```

However when there are 2 blob items in one JSON the output looks like this (it doesn't echo out the $resourceGroup,$storageAccount for the second blob item in that same JSON output).

```
$resourceGroup,$storageAccount,$blob_info
$blob_info
```

I'm thinking it's something simple I must be missing here.

Comment: Did you check what `$blob_info` contains? It may have multiple lines in which case you're not handling it correctly

Comment: @Fravadona yes for the test case I'm working on, the output is three lines from a total of 2 separate JSON objects.  The output is correct if I just echo out $blob_info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should be more correct:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
resourceGroup=$1
storageAccount=$2

IFS=$'\t\n' read -d '' -r -a containers < <(
    az storage container list \
    --auth-mode login \
    --account-name "$storageAccount" \
    --query '[].[name]' \
    -o tsv
)

# unescape TSV values
for i in "${!containers[@]}"
do
    printf -v 'containers[i]' %b "${containers[i]}"
done

for container in "${containers[@]}"
do
    while IFS='' read -r blob_info
    do
        printf '%b\n' "$(tr '\t' ',' <<< "$resourceGroup,$storageAccount,$blob_info")"
    done < <(
        az storage blob list \
            --auth-mode login \
            --account-name "$storageAccount" \
            --container-name "$container" \
            --query '[].[container,name,properties.contentLength,properties.blobTier]' \ 
            -o tsv
    )
done
```